# Does Loopback sync support document-level replication?

Tags: couchdb, replication, loopbackjs, strongloop, synchronization

I'm looking at setting up a synchronisation between device and server database using CouchDB.

The interface i'm looking at using is loopback's built-in synchronisation (soon to become loopback-component-sync). What I would like to know is if we can use document-level replication in this case. For example, we may only want to replicate data for a specific user in the database.

I'm new to this functionality and would appreciate some insight as to how this might work with loopback as the replication host/client for sync between databases.